# When to use subdocuments in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm from a MySQL background, and I might be misunderstanding the uses of Mongo's subdocs.

I have a bunch of `Users` that can write and publish `Articles`. These articles will ever be seen by that user.

Should these articles be stored with references to the `Users` or like this in the `UserSchema`:

```
articles: [ArticleSchema]
```

Comment: What you are asking is actually a little too **broad**. Can you possibly expand on "how" you are intending to use your data in your question? It would help.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb by essence allows you to replace the join by subdocuments. Keep in mind that there is no native join in Mongodb like in sql world. Depending on your query structure, you may either embed Users in articles or articles in Users.